# Application of Append section in snapshot of collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I made a collection view with diffable data source. The snapshot is defined as :

```
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, String>()
```

Section is declared as:

```
struct Section:Hashable {
    let title: String
    let items: [String]
}
```

In view controller:

```
 let sections = [Section(title: "morning", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2"]),
                        Section(title: "noon", items: ["Item 3", "Item 4"])]
        snapshot.appendSections(sections)
        for section in sections {
           snapshot.appendItems(section.items, toSection: section)
        }
```

My question is in view controller the section has already items why again we have to append items with appendItems(...) in order this to work. I tried Apple documentation and didn't quite understood why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to use `appendItems` to "append the items again" because `appendSection` just adds a section, not the items.

The two type parameters of `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` are just *identifiers* for the sections and items. Importantly, the section identifier doesn't need to contain all the items in that section - it's just something that identifies that section. You can think of this as a "name" for that section.

Based on your `Section` struct, I would use `String` as the section identifier:

```
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>()
```

The section identifiers can be the `title`s of the `Section`s.

```
let sections = [...]
snapshot.appendSections(sections.map(\.title))
for section in sections {
    snapshot.appendItems(section.items, toSection: section.title)
}
```

While it is technically possible to use `Section` itself as the section identifier (i.e. a section's "name" is its `title` combined with all its items), this is undesirable most of the time.

These identifiers help the data source figure out what to animate, when you `apply` a snapshot. The diffable data source finds the difference between the existing snapshot and the new snapshot you applied.

If you use the sections' items as the section identifier, that means every time an item is added/removed/changed, that section's identifier changes. That means the section with the old identifier is removed, and a new section with the new identifier is added. The data source would animate the removal of that whole section, and the insertion of a new section in its place.

If only the section's `title` is the identifier, the data source would know that the section hasn't changed, and it will only animate the insertion/removal/change of that particular item. While the end results are the same, the animations are very different.

Comment: Thank you for your time for explaining in detail, this helps  lot. Arigato.